# How should Vormetric be configured to secure .NET access to encrypted data

Tags: encryption, .net

We're using Vormetric to encrypt data at rest, and have a .NET application (running behind IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1)  we'd like to configure so

- The application has access to Vormetric encrypted information
- admin users cannot use their privileges to access the encrypted information

There are two parts to solving this challenge:

- configuring Vormetric so the .NET application has access to the information
- configuring Vormetric so an admin user cannot install their own .NET application which also has access to encrypted information.

Any configuration advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking their support team directly.

Comment: Would that they had an answer :-). Of course I started there - and pressed pretty firmly (and we have a good relationship with them - they're great folks - just no details forthcoming on this subject).